# Socket.IO/Node.JS execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, browser, socket.io

I'm new to both Node.JS and Socket.IO, so I decided to pick up a simple chat client as my first project. To my knowledge, it structured correctly, but I'm being thrown an `object expected` error whenever I try to run `index.js`. Anyone know what's up? (if it helps, I'm running on Windows 8.1)

Code:

> Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TNjs Chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "TNjsChat Client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A browser based chat system using Node.JS and socket.io, by Touka",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What line of code is making the error?

Comment: Also, the Express 4 recommend code for socket.io is here: http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-the-express-framework.  You're using the older version of the code which I don't know if it works with Express 4 or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/dgmueNW.png) (and thanks for the docs, I'll definitely implement a few things)

Comment: That screen shot looks to me like you're not running node.js.  You would normally start index.js with a command line "node index.js" and node.exe would be in the path.

Comment: @jfriend00 if I run `node index.js` (with the correct filepath for index) I get `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`

Comment: Then, that's because express isn't installed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run node, not just let Microsoft IE run the js file which is what your screenshot seems to show.

Make sure node.exe is in the path somewhere and then run "node index.js" from the index.js directory and make sure all modules you need (like Express) are installed properly and available from the index.js directory.